# How to get a private key from seed phrase on solana?

Tags: rust, smartcontracts, solana, wallet

I stored public key and seed phrase in safe place, but not the private key.
When I add my wallet on phantom, it asks to add private key instead of seed phrase.
Any solutions? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution 1: navigate to the keypair json on your system. i.e. `.config/solana/id.json`. Then you can find out the array for the private key.

Solution 2: you can use solana web3 SDK.

```
  let seed = Uint8Array.from(
    SEED_STRING.split(",")
  ).slice(0, 32);

  // create keypairs
  let KEYPAIRS = web3.Keypair.fromSeed(seed);
  console.log(KEYPAIRS.privateKey);
```

Comment: I think I don't need Solution 2. I tried the Solution 1 and it worked fine. Also, from Solution 2, I get the same result as id.json

Answer (score 2):

I found the better way.

```
const keypair = Keypair.fromSecretKey(
  Uint8Array.from([
    174, 47, 154, 16, 202, 193, 206, 113, 199, 190, 53, 133, 169, 175, 31, 56,
    222, 53, 130, 189, 220, 216, 117, 173, 10, 149, 53, 45, 73, 251, 237, 246,
    15, 185, 186, 82, 177, 240, 148, 69, 241, 227, 167, 80, 141, 89, 240, 121,
    121, 35, 172, 247, 68, 251, 226, 218, 48, 63, 176, 109, 168, 89, 238, 135,
  ])
);
```